# Suggested Approach in dealing with repetitive Prolog / Body / Epilog Pattern

Tags: c++

I have a scenario, where I have quite a few functions with the following pattern

```
RETURN_TYPE FOO(
    TYPE PARM1,
    TYPE PARM2)
    {
    PROLOG(PARM1, PARM2);
    //FOO_BODY
    EPILOG(PARM1, PARM2);
    }
```

Consider an example function following the above pattern

```
SQLRETURN SQLGetInfo(
    SQLHDBC         ConnectionHandle,
    SQLUSMALLINT    InfoType,
    SQLPOINTER      InfoValuePtr,
    SQLSMALLINT     BufferLength,
    SQLSMALLINT *   StringLengthPtr)
    {
    // ******** Prolog(InfoValuePtr, BufferLength) *************
    CComSafeArray<BYTE> _InfoValuePtr(BufferLength);
    LPBYTE pData;
    // **********************************************************
    SQLRETURN  rc =  p->SQLGetInfo(
        reinterpret_cast<PSSQLHSTMT>(ConnectionHandle),
        InfoType,
        _InfoValuePtr,
        BufferLength,
        StringLengthPtr);
    // ******** Epilog(InfoValuePtr) ******************************
    ::SafeArrayAccessData(_InfoValuePtr, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pData));
    memcpy_s(InfoValuePtr, BufferLength, pData, _InfoValuePtr.GetCount());
    ::SafeArrayUnaccessData(_InfoValuePtr);
    return rc;
    // *************************************************************
    }
```

My dilemma is, I am bit uncomfortable repeating the same code pattern again and again, which is prone to error during development and quite a code bloat. Even tomorrow, changing something would literally mean to meticulously change each and every occurrence to be in coherence with the change.

What is the suggested way/best practise of handling the pattern? `Macros`, `Templates`

**Note** We are still not using boost and adding boost just to solve this problem may not be an option here

Comment: template is always the cleanest solution, but when it doesn't help much, then [boost.preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) is your best friend. I'm always in favor of macros when otherwise code repetition is necessary, because I consider easy maintenance to be of uttermost importance, while legibility is only a part of it.

Comment: I can hardly write a single line of c++ without boost nowadays.

Comment: @brunocodutra: There are something developer may not have much say when working on a large organization, so lets keep that discussion out of this thread as of now :-). Also, I would love to see how we can solve this issue using templates

Answer (score 1):

@Abhijit:  My own gut feel also goes toward templates.  But, your example above doesn't really look like the simplified model you gave above it.  If you really do have a large number of functions that look the same except for some middle portion, then a template can clean that up.  Make your template argument a function pointer to a function that hooks to the prolog and epilog.  This is almost a variant of currying, but not exactly.

Without completely understanding your example above, the following is a sketch of how you might transform it to use a template.  Since the body of your example is just a function call, this transformation doesn't really expose the power of the pattern.  But, it should hopefully give an idea.

```
// Define the "body function" in a typedef, for sanity's sake
typedef SQLRETURN 
            (*SQLGetInfoFunc)(
                PSSQLHSTMT, 
                SQLUSMALLINT,
                CComSafeArray<BYTE>,
                SQLSMALLINT, 
                SQLSMALLINT*
            );  

// Templated version of SQLGetInfo
template <SQLGetInfoFunc *F>
SQLRETURN SQLGetInfo(
    SQLHDBC         ConnectionHandle,
    SQLUSMALLINT    InfoType,
    SQLPOINTER      InfoValuePtr,
    SQLSMALLINT     BufferLength,
    SQLSMALLINT *   StringLengthPtr)
    {
    // ******** Prolog(InfoValuePtr, BufferLength) *************
    CComSafeArray<BYTE> _InfoValuePtr(BufferLength);
    LPBYTE pData;
    // **********************************************************
    SQLRETURN  rc =  F(
        reinterpret_cast<PSSQLHSTMT>(ConnectionHandle),
        InfoType,
        _InfoValuePtr,
        BufferLength,
        StringLengthPtr);
    // ******** Epilog(InfoValuePtr) ******************************
    ::SafeArrayAccessData(_InfoValuePtr, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pData));
    memcpy_s(InfoValuePtr, BufferLength, pData, _InfoValuePtr.GetCount());
    ::SafeArrayUnaccessData(_InfoValuePtr);
    return rc;
    // *************************************************************
    }
```

In this example, `F` is a function pointer that you'll provide as a template parameter.  That said, I notice your original example used `p->SQLGetInfo`, but I didn't see where `p` was defined.

In the interest of providing a complete example showing the basic pattern, consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef int (*fxn)(int);

inline int fred(int x) 
{
    return x + 100;
}

inline int barney(int x)
{
    return x + 200;
}


template <fxn F>
void apply_to_array(int *array, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        array[i] = F(array[i]);
}

using namespace std;

void print_array(int *array, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        cout << " " << array[i];

    cout << endl;
}


int af[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int ab[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

int main(void)
{
    cout << "Before: af = ";
    print_array(af, 10);

    apply_to_array<fred>(af, 10);

    cout << "After apply_to_array<fred>(af):  af = ";
    print_array(af, 10);

    cout << "Before: ab = ";
    print_array(ab, 10);

    apply_to_array<barney>(ab, 10);

    cout << "After apply_to_array<barney>(ab):  ab = ";
    print_array(ab, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs the following:

```
Before: af =  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
After apply_to_array<fred>(af):  af =  101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
Before: ab =  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
After apply_to_array<barney>(ab):  ab =  201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would need some time to understand this pattern to suit my need as few customization is required but any case I like your Idea. Please note, I am planning to open a bounty for this in the coming days, and wait for few more answers. If yours is the one that works I will award you the bounty. Till then I am keeping my options open :-)

Comment: @Couple of things if you need clarity. 1. `p` is the pointer to the COM Interface 2. This would still require to duplicate the code (but there are opportunities I can see), as variable names vary from functions but the type and actions remains the same. 3. It won;t matter if the called function is a method or not, as a pointer to a member function can easily be wrapped.